Taylor Expansion of exp(exp(x))
I can think of two ways to work out the taylor expansion of exp(exp(x)) about x=0.

Just differentiating normally and plugging in x=0. You get:

f'(x) = exp(x)exp(exp(x))
so f'(0) = e
f''(x) = exp(x)exp(exp(x)) + exp(2x)exp(exp(x))
so f''(0) = e + e = 2e
And so you get the taylor expansion:
f(x) = e + ex + 2ex^2/2! + ...

Plugging in the taylor expansion for exp(x) into the taylor expansion for exp(x).
We know exp(x) = 1 + x + x^2/2! + ...

But if you work out 1 + (1 + x + x^2/2! + ... ) + (1 + x + x^2/2! + ... )^2/2! + ...
you get a different taylor expansion to the one above.
Can someone please help me understand what's going on.

Which difference do you spot there?

What Jose said.  My guess: you made an error.  But you do not show enough to let us find it.

Ok, thank you for your comments. I've added more steps now.

"There are clearly no $e$'s" ... what is the constant term of $1 + (1 + x + x^2/2! + ... ) + (1 + x + x^2/2! + ... )^2/2!+...;$?  Answer ... $1 + 1 + 1/2! + \dots$.  The constant term is exactly $e$.  Next, do the degree $1$  terms.

I’m voting to close this question because no use of latex

Since
$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$
Substitute $z=e^x$
$$e^{(e^x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^x)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nx}}{n!}$$
Another way would be to find the Maclaurin series using the definition (like you tried)
Let $f(x)=e^{(e^X)}$
$f(0)=e \\ f'(0)=e \\ f''(0)=2e\\ f^{(3)}(0)=5e\\.\\.\\.$
And we get that
$$e^{(e^x)}=e+ex+\frac{2e}{2!}x^2+\frac{5e}{3!}x^3 +\dots = e+ex+ex^2+\frac{5e}{3!}x^3+ \dots$$

I suggest you factor out $e$ and collapse the sum for a cleaner looking solution

@RyRytheFlyGuy clearer, perhaps, but, fwiw, if one factors out the e, it's no longer, strictly speaking, a TS.

No, it is simply expressing the TS in a compact way

More compactly $$e^{e^x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e, B_n}{n!}, x^n=e, \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n}{n!}, x^n$$ where $B_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Bell number.

$1+(1+x+x^2/2+…)+(1+x+x^2/2+…)^2/2+(1+x+x^2/2+…)^3/6=
 1+1+x+x^2/2+1/2+x^2/2+x^4/8+x+x^2/2+x^3/2+1/6+x^3/6+x^6/12+x^2/2+x/2+x^4/8+x^2/4+x^5/8+x^4/4+x^3/2+…=(1+1+1/2+1/6…)+(1+1+1/2+…)x+(1/2+1/2+1/2+1/2+1/4+…)x^2+…=e+ex+ex^2+…$
